# How can I pass either type or value to _Generic()

Tags: c, macros

The `sizeof` builtin can take either a type or an expression, and will return the appropriate value.

I'd like to build a macro that uses `_Generic()` expressions to do something similar. In particular, I'd like to be able to pass either a type name or a value as the parameter, just like `sizeof`.

As a trivial example, I can do something like this:

```
#define F(x)  _Generic((x)+0, int: 1, long: 2)
```

That works because `(x)+0` can be either an arithmetic expression or a type cast.

- (1)+0 -> 1+0 -> 1 -> int: 1
- (long)+0 -> 0L -> long: 2

But that doesn't work when the type is `struct Foo`.

I could use composite literal syntax, with curly braces: `(x){0}` but that fails for literal values:

- (long){0} - works
- (struct Foo){0} - works
- (1){0} - not so much. :-(

Is there some twisted C syntax horror that will permit the use of either type names or expressions in a `_Generic`-expression?

Comment: Yes, but `_Generic((x)+0, int: 1, long: 2)` only handles 2 two types.  If you want is to handle more types like `struct foo`, `double`, `char *`, ... You will need those types in your `_Generic` list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your compound literal idea will work if you combine it with `typeof`.
However, please note that `typeof` is a a GCC C language extension, so it might not work in every C compiler.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Foo {
  int mx;
} Foo;

#define F(x) _Generic((typeof(x)){0}, \
  int: 1, \
  long: 2, \
  struct Foo: 3)

int main()
{
  printf("%d\n", F(0));         // 1
  printf("%d\n", F(int));       // 1
  printf("%d\n", F((long)0));   // 2
  printf("%d\n", F(long));      // 2
  printf("%d\n", F((Foo){1}));  // 3
  printf("%d\n", F(Foo));       // 3
}
```

Comment: "*typeof is a a GCC C language extension*" Yes, and one that will hopefully be officially blessed by C23